# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2}\ dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Check whether the series
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2}\ dx$$
>   is convergent.

I tried to sandwich the function by $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$ , but this did not help at all.
Any other way of approaching?

Comment: Have you tried evaluating the integral as a function of $n$ and then checking for convergence of the series?

Comment: Are you sure the "sandwich" method doesn't work? You only need an upper bound as the integral is clearly positive for all $n$.

Comment: Not found a legit function yet

Comment: @zzuussee the integral is quite clumsy

Comment: Have you tried adding a variable and using Leibniz integral rule to get a simpler form of the integral then writing this as a summation?

Comment: @LegendKiller Ah right I see, was just my first reflex.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{x} / (1+x^2) < \sqrt{x}$...

Comment: @JairTaylor, this comment is gold. Could not figure the upper bound since thought only about the nominator :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $x\in [0,1], \frac {\sqrt x}{2} \le\frac {\sqrt x}{1+x^2} \le \sqrt x$

Which means that $\frac 12\int_0^\frac1n \sqrt x\ dx \le \int_0^\frac1n \frac {\sqrt x}{1+x^2} \ dx \le \int_0^\frac1n \sqrt x \ dx$

if $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^\frac1n \sqrt x \ dx $ converges then  $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^\frac1n \frac{\sqrt x}{1+x^2} \ dx $ converges.

and if $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^\frac1n \sqrt x \ dx $ diverges then $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^\frac1n \frac 12\sqrt x \ dx $ diverges and   $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^\frac1n \frac{\sqrt x}{1+x^2} \ dx $ diverges.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{\sqrt x}{1+x^2}dx<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{\sqrt x}{1}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{3n^{3/2}}=\frac{2}{3}\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sqrt{x}$ is increasing and $1/(1+x^2)$ is decreasing, we have
$$ \int_0^{1/n} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2} \, dx < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \int_0^{1/n}\frac{dx}{1+x^2} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \int_0^{1/n} dx = \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}.  $$
 And $\sum_n 1/n^{3/2}$ converges.

Comment: This is wrong, the integral of $1/(1+x^2)$ is not $\log(1+x^2)$.

Comment: Yes, thank you everyone, there were a couple of errors in there to start with. Now corrected. Perhaps downvoters would like to reconsider?

Answer (score 2):

I think you tried to estimate the wrong part of the fraction. If you think about it, $\sqrt{x}$ is much different from 1 and from $x$ in a close neighborhood of 0. However, $1+x^2$ is very close to 1 there. 
So simply estimate by $\int\limits_{0}^{1/n} \sqrt{x}= \frac{2}{3}n^{-3/2}$, whose sum is convergent.

Comment: I think it would make your answer better if you also add the fact that $1+x^2 \geq 1$ on the interval $(0,1/n)$. Thus, indeed, your estimate is an upperbound :)

Comment: A matter of taste, but thank you for the feedback anyway. I thought that part was self-explanatory.

Comment: True true. Have a nice day!